# How to find if FC-Switch using port-zoning or not Brocade FC 300

Tags: storage, fiber, san

I have to replace a HBA on RedHat5.3 due to card failure.

A tech guy asked me that
"Check your FC-Switch Zoning Type of Port Zoning or not? ,
because if host accessed by WWNN, you'll need to update FC-switch config"

Is this below result on Brocade FC 300 showing Port-Zoning configuration or not?

```
fcsw03:admin> switchshow
switchName:     xxxxx
switchType:     71.2
switchState:    Online
switchMode:     Native
switchRole:     Principal
switchDomain:   1
switchId:       fffc01
switchWwn:      10:00xxxxxxxxxxxxx
zoning:         ON (zones)
switchBeacon:   OFF

Index Port Address Media Speed State     Proto
==============================================
  0   0   011700   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  1   1   011500   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 21:00:00:24:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  2   2   011300   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  3   3   011100   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  4   4   011600   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  5   5   011400   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  6   6   011200   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 50:06:01:60:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  7   7   011000   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 50:06:01:69:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  8   8   010f00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
  9   9   010d00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 10  10   010b00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 11  11   010900   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 12  12   010e00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 13  13   010c00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 14  14   010a00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 15  15   010800   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is to check *zoneshow* command output to list all configured zones. Zones that look like:

```
zone:test_1
         21:00:00:24:XX:XX:XX:XX
         50:06:01:60:XX:XX:XX:XX
         50:06:01:69:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Are using WWN addresses.

If you see something like:

```
zone:test_1
         1,1
         1,6
         1,7
```

Then, you are using port-zoning. Here, the first 1 is the SwitchDomain ID and 1,6,7 are port numbers on that switch.

Also, zones can have a mixture of WWNs and ports definitions. Don't forget to do the same on the second Brocade switch as they are usually implementing Dual-Fabric configuration for redundancy and multi-pathing.